# How to show a gridview, run something in the background and update the gridview with the results

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridview where one of the columns is expensive to generate. I'd like to show the gridview replacing the expensive values with spinners, then automatically update the values as they are generated.

I'm relatively new to ASP.Net, and so kind of lost about how to do this. Maybe it can be done with a web service and a javascript call for each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maybe it can be done with a web service and a javascript call for each value?`
this.

Of course it would be a better idea to use a single ajax call to get all the necessary values at once to prevent too many requests to your web server.

Anyway, this isn't specific to asp.net, but rather to web development. Doesn't matter if you use php, asp.net, java, python or ruby on rails, the process would be pretty much the same. HTTP is stateless, so your server doesn't know when your client has finished rendering the page. You need to use javascript (ajax) to query the server when your client is ready.

Comment: What made me doubt was [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says: "This topic pertains to a legacy technology. XML Web services and XML Web service clients should now be created using **Windows Communication Foundation**."

Comment: @ASalazar, that applies to `XML Web Services`, not to web services in general. :)